# How to select only one of the objects in a json file

Tags: php, json

Hi I'm currently trying to do an API request. The API sends out a json request like this:

```json
[
 {
  "name": "Test 1"
  "yes-or-no": "yes"
 },
 {
  "name": "Test 2"
  "yes-or-no": "no"
 }
]
```

My question is, how do I select one of the `yes-or-no` to echo in the website? I tried doing this:

```php
<?php
$status = json_decode(file_get_contents('url to the json file'));
// Display message AKA uptime.
foreach ($status->yes-or-no as $answer) {
    echo $answer.'<br />';
}
?>
```

But didn't work.

I'm sorry if I got some terms wrong, since I'm pretty new to coding APIs like this.

EDIT: Please see the answer below. It works but now my question is: How do I only display one of them? Instead of both of them displaying at the same time.

Comment: `$status->{'yes-or-no'}` ??

Comment: a variable property or occurance name of `yes-or-no` is invalid in PHP ( hyphens are not allowed in variable names). So if you have any control over the returned data from this API ask them to make the names valid

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is really not called `yes-or-no`, I'm just really using that as an example currently.

Comment: Dear high reppers, please identify basic questions and close them as duplicates so that Stack Overflow doesn't have to keep collecting redundant content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but maybe i can shed some light into the question:

```
$status = json_decode(file_get_contents('url to the json file'), true);
```

Add ", true" this will make your $status an array instead of an object.

```
foreach ($status as $answer) {
    echo $answer['yes-or-no'].'<br />'; //output yes or no
    echo $answer['name'].'<br />'; //output test 1 or test 2
}
```

Comment: Why do people always want to convert perfectly good objects into arrays?

Comment: For me it‘s just that i prefer the Syntax. I think it‘s easier when working with JavaScript, but maybe that‘s just me. Apart from that, i just tried to help.

Comment: This works, but how do I only display one at a time? Instead of both?

Comment: foreach will loop over all the items. If you would only display one item you can get it via $status[0]['name'] <- this will take the first item $status[1]['name'] will be the second. for a random item you could count the items in the status and display it via a random function.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$statuses = json_decode(file_get_contents('url to the json file'));

foreach ($statuses as $status) {
    echo $status->{'yes-or-no'};
}
?>
```